# Call jquery Plugin function from outside

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Today I am Learning "How to create plugin in jQuery"

I am having a table having lots of columns initially I am setting  display none to all columns and set limited number of columns visible to user.
And providing Next and previous buttons to for showing next and previous columns.

I want to call `SetColumns_ColumnPagingTable()` function of Plugin on click of Next and previous buttons.

How can I achieve it. Please Help .

Thanks in Advance.

Please Note : Right Now both the buttons are statically  placed. In future I will create  them dynamically.
 My jsfiddle link  - 
http://jsfiddle.net/saurabh29/Legh6re1/

Comment: please share some relevant code that you have tried so far

Comment: @Bhushan : Please use jsFiddle Link :  http://jsfiddle.net/saurabh29/Legh6re1/

Comment: How are you using jquery library and which version?

Comment: Jquery  version : Jquery 1.11.0 .And Simply using jquery for creating plugin

Comment: Check this.http://jsfiddle.net/Legh6re1/3/
You can get the return of ColumnPagingTable to a variable and using that refrence call SetColumns_ColumnPagingTable method.   myTableReference= $("#myTable").ColumnPagingTable({
                showColumns: 5
            });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.Updated Fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/Legh6re1/4/
If you are going to create Previous and Next buttons dynamically in future.Then you can move the code inside SetColumns_ColumnPagingTable to click events of those buttons.

```
     (function ($) {$.fn.ColumnPagingTable = function (options) {
                   ....
                   ....


var previousButton=$("<input />", { id: "btnNext_ColumnPagingTable",value: "Previous" ,type:"button"});
                previousButton.click(function() {

                        var rows = document.getElementById('myTable').rows;
                        var pointer = 0;
                        for (var row = 0; pointer < rows.length; row++, pointer++) {
                            var cols = rows[pointer].cells;
                            cols[endVisibleIndex].style.display = false ? '' : 'none';
                            cols[startVisibleIndex - 1].style.display = true ? '' : 'none';
                            endVisibleIndex--;
                            startVisibleIndex--;

                        }

                    });
 $(this).parent().append(previousButton);
```

Comment: Thanks  for replying ..But What I want to allow end user to define only  showColumns variable and nothing . I have to  internally call jquery plugin function.

Comment: Thanks @DeshanR : It solved my Problem. But Is it posiible, can I call function like "hideAllColumns_ColumnPagingTable" or   "SetColumns_ColumnPagingTable"  from within                                                                                    previousButton.click(function() {        }); " event  that you have written.

Answer (score 0):

You can save your jquery plugin code in some `.js` file, lets say `jQuery-custom-plugin.js` and add it below your jquery library plugin using `<script></script>` tag.

see below

```
<script src="/<your path upto js file>/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<script src="/<your path upto js file>/jQuery-custom-plugin.js"></script>
```

**NOTE** - here `<your path upto js file>` is the actual path till js file.

and then call the plugin function inside `document.ready` as shown below

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   myTableReference= $("#myTable").ColumnPagingTable({
           showColumns: 5
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for replying ..But What I want to allow end user to define only showColumns variable and nothing . I have to internally call jquery plugin function